# How to get Diamond Extreme 7.1 in Natty working

Tags: sound, multimedia, soundcard, output

I am trying to set up the Diamond Extreme 7.1 DDL in Natty. The only thing that works are the analog outputs.

But in order to enjoy movies with DD 5.1 or DTS I need the optical out to function. Another problem is that my old Yamaha receiver doesn't handle DTS directly, so I need either Dolby Digital Live to transform it or ffdshow audio codecs (throughput to spdif only results in noise). And third, I am addicted to DDL to enjoy stereo sources in surround sound. DDL works much better than Dolby Prologic II.

Any idea how to get this working in Natty? At least I need to get the optical out working (though Dolby Digital Live is also very desirable). I tried to set things in alsa mixer but without results. Coming from the Windows side and being new to Ubuntu I really have a hard time to get things working the way I was used to. Is there at least some similar codec pack like ffdshow that I could use in Ubuntu?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see what your system sees your Sound card as! Type in Terminal  `lspci -v | less`  This will check your computer's motherboard, and attempt to list out all devices that it's recognized as installed. There is probably a lot of things listed, but the one you're looking for will be labeled ***Audio device***.

Most users have a "built in" sound card for their computer on the motherboard. If yours is built in, and isn't showing up in this step, then you probably need to enable it in your BIOS. When you first boot, or reboot your computer, there's usually a key sequence telling you how to enter the BIOS Configuration Screen. You'll need to sort through your BIOS and enable the built in sound card.

If you are not using a built in sound card, and this step does not show your audio card, the card may be seated incorrectly on your motherboard, or may be bad or otherwise incompatible with your motherboard. You will probably want to test the card in another computer to see if it works there.